# jQuery keypress event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that when the user hits edit, it changes the field from text to a textbox with a class of cat_name_edit.

The following code does not trigger when pressing any key in the textbox.  Could it have something to do with the fact that I've already changed the text into a textbox?

```
  $(".cat_name_edit").keypress(function() {

     alert("hi"); 

  });
```

I've also tried .click() and .keydown() with no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this inside 'ready' function ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently I had to use .live()

Comment: You can also try with `.on()` or `.delegate()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the elements are not present on page load so the events are not attached. Try using jQuery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$(".cat_name_edit").live('keypress', (function() {

     alert("hi"); 

  });
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()

Answer (score 0):

I put this into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/cWjMF/) `keypress()` works fine:

```
$(".cat_name_edit").keypress(function(e) {
    $(this).replaceWith("<textarea class=\"cat_name_edit\"></textarea>");
    $("textarea.cat_name_edit").focus();
});
```

`keyup()` would have worked too.

I've also gone to the liberty of making the function that replaces the input with a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

or you could also use EventDelegation. Attach your click event to the parent which contains these textboxes, and in the function check if the target that was clicked has the class cat_name_edit and then perform your operation.